# How can I get the band (2.4 / 5 GHz) selection back in wifi settings? (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: wireless, settings, 20.04

I upgraded Ubuntu to 20.04 and the setting for preferred WiFi frequency has disappeared. You can see a screenshot of the drop-down menu here:

[image: ss]

How can I get this drop down menu back?

#### References

- [How to set wifi driver settings to prefer 5 GHz channel above 2.4 GHz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183525/how-to-set-wifi-driver-settings-to-prefer-5-ghz-channel-above-2-4-ghz)

Comment: Use `nm-connection-editor`.

Comment: @heynnema - I think this is worth an answer, for the benefit of the community.

Answer (score 10):

The dropdown menu was removed from the UI (I could not find the reason).

But there is a work-around, by checking the [manual](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-settings.html) of `nm-settings`:

- Locate the targeted WiFi connection profile in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/nameofconnection.nmconnection`
- edit with `sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/nameofconnection.nmconnection`
- Under section `[wifi]` add following entry

  - for 2.4 GHz only `band=bg`
  - for 5 GHz only `band=a`
- save changes and connection should use the new configuration

Comment: Or run the command that is posted as a comment on the question (`nm-connection-editor` in the terminal)

Answer (score 8):

Credits for @heynnema

To access the settings in a GUI execute `nm-connection-editor` in a terminal.
Then choose your desired connection and click on edit.

Thanks. This did the trick for me!