# Is there a UI option for changing the frequency of the WIFI connection in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: wireless, 20.04, system-settings

I know there is an option to do it manually by changing the files in /etc/NetworkManager 
But is there an option where I can modify the wifi settings for my connections without having to do that every time?

Comment: What are you modifying in /etc/NetworkManager? Have you tried `nm-connection-editor`?

Comment: @heynnema The procedure I followed is mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231022/how-can-i-get-the-band-2-4-5-ghz-selection-back-in-wifi-settings-ubuntu-20)

I did not try  `nm-connection-editor` before. Thank you it has the options I need. For some reason these options are not included in the network settings which was not the case in previous versions of ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

In `terminal`, use `nm-connection-editor`.